# Can't transfer ringtone to iPhone or remove existing from library

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, ringtones

I'm using iTunes 12.7 and iOS 11.3. A while ago I added a long list of custom ringtones that are still in my phone. iTunes can't see them (Tones section is blank). I can use iExplorer to delete the files from iTunes_control, and they then disappear off the phone, but the iExplorer media library still shows them there.

At the same time, I can't transfer any new ringtones to the phone. When I try through iTunes, the files remain greyed out and never transfer to the phone. When I try through iExplorer, the files transfer but never appear on the phone.

View from iExplorer (these are the old ringtones):
[image]

View from iTunes (these are the ringtones I'm trying to transfer):
[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've gotten it working. Using iExplorer, I deleted the entire /iTunes_control/Ringtones folder, and then **also** deleted /iTunes_control/iTunes/Ringtones.plist. Restarted the phone, transferred new ringtones through iTunes, and both the Ringtones folder and .plist file were regenerated with the correct values.